# Inbox got nuked after datacenter shift

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

[image]

I can't see any items in my inbox aside from the stuff I got *after* the datacenter shift.

My notifications box is all right, though.

My [inbox tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/1212053/manishearth?tab=inbox) shows all my messages as well:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help you, but mine seems fine.

Comment: Empty here as well, was going to report but you beat me to it. :)